# kotlin-test vs kotlin-test-junit

Tags: kotlin, junit, kotlintest

I have a kotlin project that is compiled to java.
My test library is junit.
Im using maven as my dependency management and Intellij IDEA.
recently I got that strange warning in my pom.

> Inspection info: If you have kotlin-test and junit dependency then
> most likely you better to include kotlin-test-junit instead of just
> kotlin-test

What is the difference between kotlin-test and kotlin-test-junit?

from what I read it seems that kotlin-test is not deprecated, so Why did intellij recommend kotlin-test-junit instead of kotlin-test?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I found the answer [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/) (I don't understand how I missed it in my first search)

In short `kotlin-test` library provides a set of annotations and utility functions independently of the test framework.

Where `kotlin-test-junit` library provides an implementation on top of Junit Asserter and the annotations and utility functions `kotlin-test` provides.